# ios app publishing, how to replace a rejected version with a new one

Tags: ios, ipad, app-store-connect

Pardon me for beginner's question

I had an iPhone app released. When I updated to a new version (in the sceenshot, it's 1.1.4), it got rejected due to `app did not run at iPhone resolution when reviewed on iPad running iOS 10.3.1`

So I fix it by changing the app and publishing it as Universal app, so that it can run on iPad with iPad resolution (instead of iPhone 4 rez).

I already uploaded it (version 1.1.5), but I don't see the option to publish it (the context menu iOS app is greyed out, as in the second screenshot).

I already checked the Apple developer guide but it doesn't have the case how to remove a rejected app. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/About.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH1-SW1

How do I remove the rejected app and replace it with the new one? Thanks

[image: First screenshot]
[image: Second screenshot]

Comment: just increase build number! keep version as it is! !

Answer (score 2):

Increase the build number and create a new archive.

So version 1.1.4 Build 2

Answer (score 1):

After the application rejected
1: resolve the problem due to which apple reject the application.
2: increase the build number **(Not application version)**, (in your case AppVersion same as before 1.1.4 and build number 2.0 )
3: create new archive
4: upload the AppStore 
5: Submit to AppStore

Let me know if you face any difficulty